# File upload with React and NodeJs is not transmitting data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload an image from a React form to a NodeJS server using a FormData object and Fetch. However, the general information in the FormData object and the file are being reported as {} and undefined by the Node server.

React Code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('title', state.title);
            formData.append('posterAddress', state.posterAddress);
            formData.append('file', file);
            fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/memes`, {
                body: formData,
                method: 'POST',
            }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then(setLoading(false))
            .catch((err) => {
                window.alert(err);
            });
```

Node Code:

```
export const create = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const file = req.files;
    const bodyData = req.body;

    console.log(file);
    console.log(bodyData);
};
```

Comment: When you use the post method you only send the information and you do not receive any content in response (except that you configure it as such). You can debug to see if all your information is loaded in the FormData object (frontend), then debug on the server (backend) to see if you receive the formdata, if not, configure the multer correctly

Comment: It is the backend. Those console.log's return "undefined" and "{}". However, if I do formData.get('title') to check that the front end is loading the information correctly it works.